# Cannot run Helloworld in cocos2d-x 3.11: Fatal Signal 11

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, fatal-error

I'm new to cocos2d-x, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_Start_A_New_Cocos2D-X_Game)

It's working well on the iOS platform, but not on Android.

I tried to setup cocos2d-x again and again, both cocos2d-x 3.11, 3.8, 3.6; tried with Android NDK r11c, r10e, r9d; tried to run in terminal and Eclipse, but the program cannot run and gives an error `Fatal Signal 11`.

It's work well with cocos2d-x 2.2.6, but I don't want to use it.
I'm using Genymotion.

Can anyone show me where my error lies?

This is my logcat:

```
05-16 22:02:43.979: D/dalvikvm(2395): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sangle.mygametest11-2/libMyGame.so 0xa4f9ab10
05-16 22:02:44.339: A/libc(2395): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x000000b4 (code=1), thread 2395 (le.mygametest11)
```

Comment: Attach full log, with DEBUG section

Comment: hi Petrov, I added my log in Eclipse.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the template project generated by the cocos command line tool?

Comment: Do you use 'cocos run -p android' to run the app?

Comment: @Araon, Makalele: No and Yes, I go to cocos2d-x folder, run setup.py, and then run 'cocos new ...'  and 'cocos run -p android...' in terminal. The game is crash at this step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compile it through the console and if error occurs post it here.

Go to android folder inside your project through cmd run "build_setup.py".

Comment: Thanks Dhiraj, it's work. And sorry for late comment

Comment: You can mark this solved. And put a correct mark to the answer so others can also get help from this.